# why is Non- Enum value being used in Url

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

Basically my enum value determine's the page your on (in the url)and I have the below "if" statement to cover the stituation , if a user enters a load of text in the url it defaults to "New"......put if I enter any number other then the Enum values it displays that number instead of the default "New" page.

I don't want to post a load of code so hopefully it's clear, it redirects correctly if text entered in URL, but not for non-enum value. Is there a way to check if the Url input matches a enum value ?

ActionResult

```
            [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string status, string message)
    {

        var referralStatus = ReferralStatus.New;

        if (!Enum.TryParse(status, out referralStatus))
        {
            referralStatus = ReferralStatus.New;
        }

        var model = new ReferralsModel();
        model.Status = referralStatus.ToString();

        model.ReferralsCount.Status = referralStatus.ToString();


        return View(model);
    }
```

Your url when landing on the Index page reads..
project/Referrals , 
your url after selecting a tab on the page reads...
project/Referrals?Status=2  ,
your url when entering diferent numbers in the Url
project/Refferals?status =56473  ,
your view renders with these numbers in place of enum status value.

please note this is an asp.net mvc 4 application

Comment: So I can't be certain, but the problem is probably related to routing. The default routing scheme would map an integral value to the `id` parameter.

Comment: is there no way of just adding to the "if" statement to check the enums, as there is only 6 ? The problem in the above is the status property will be the value entered in the URL, so I need to check that ? but what would the syntax for that be and would it be the best way to achieve goal..

Comment: Have you tried declaring referralStatus with its real enum type, and without setting a value, instead of `var referralStatus = ReferralStatus.New;` ?

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean ?

Comment: I mean `ReferralStatus referralStatus;` instead of `var referralStatus = ReferralStatus.New;`

Comment: Same result..thanks anyway

Comment: is status a string containing an integer ? If so, you should try to convert it to int before trying to cast it to ReferralStatus .

Comment: Yes it is a  string which contains an int, declared as follows in the ActionResult - public ActionResult Index(string status, string message)

Comment: Same result, I need to check if status equals one of enum values and if not assign the enum value of new to status (and then to referralStatus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit : As stated in the comments, you may use `Enum.IsDefined` for parsing int representation of Enum

```
 if (!Enum.TryParse(status, out referralStatus))
```

should be

```
 if (!Enum.TryParse(status, out referralStatus) || !Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ReferralStatus),referralStatus))
```

---

From your comments, maybe you can try something like :

```
ReferralStatus referralStatus;

try{
   referralStatus = (ReferralStatus) int.Parse(status);       
}
catch{
    status = ((int)ReferralStatus.New).ToString();
    referralStatus = ReferralStatus.New;   
}
```

Comment: Same problem , status value is equal to whatever gets typed into the url.. apart from text, its deals with that correctly

Comment: @mkell I confess I can't see how this is possible. Could you post the whole action method, as well as the point where it is checked that status has the wrong value ?

Comment: @mkell As you are manipulating integer representation of enum as string, you should add a call to Enum.IsDefined. see example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx